# This code work is working on my Php myadmin but not on my live database "0 results" shows up

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm login in from my log in screen to my reports this code work on my localhost but dose not want to work on my live dataBase can anyone tell me why I'm using FileZila

```
    <?php

SESSION_start();

require_once '../config.php';

/* Logining in the users */
if(isset($_POST['Login']) && $_POST['Login'] == 1){
    //print_r($_POST);

    //Variables
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    // check if there is a user with the same password

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM afm_user WHERE Email = '$email' AND Password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // print_r($email);

    //print_r($result);die();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $row['Email'];
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['id'];
        }
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

}
```

Hi I have addded this

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $row['Email'];
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['id'];
        }
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    } else {
        echo("0 results" . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

}
```

all that is showing is "0 results" if anyone can exsplaine why it works on myAdmin and not FileZila

Comment: what does show up; "0 results"?

Comment: Yes @FunkFortyNiner "0 results" shows up

Comment: your query may have failed you then. Best you enable error reporting and use `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm Doing that will give you feedback

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner All that shows in the 0 results